# Does Safari support Objective-C app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mobile-safari

I'm wondering it there is a way to build an Objective-C applications and then integrate into an HTML page so it can be open from iPhone, Safari. Is that possible?

I'm thinking to be something similar with Flash application embedded on HTML pages by using a Flash Player plugin.

Cheers,
Codrin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. But you can use [**Cappuccino**](http://cappuccino.org/), which is web framework for Objective-C developers.

Answer (score 0):

Safari is not build to run Objective-C apps..

You should submit your application to the AppsStore, which is the best way to distribute application over the iPhone platform.